# @PreAuthorize on JpaRepository

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I am looking to implement role based security for my REST service. I am using spring-data-rest and have configured a `JpaRepository` as such:

```
@Repository
@RestResource(path = "changesets", rel = "changesets")
public interface ChangesetRepository extends JpaRepository<Changeset, Long> { }
```

I would like to attach a `@PreAuthorize` annotation to the inherited `Page<T> findAll(Pageable pageable)` method so that a GET requires a specific role.

Is there a way to do that? Do I need to provide a custom implementation or am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add your own parent class for all repositories (see [how to do it in the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.4.3.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html#repositories.custom-behaviour-for-all-repositories)). Then just add all necessary annotations and your security restrictions  will be applied for all child beans.

From the architecture point of view most of the time a Repository is not the right place to apply your security restrictions. Your service layer is much more appropriate place (because your security restrictions depend on your business actions and not on your data loading logic). Consider following example: you want to reuse the same Repository in many Services, and security rules are not the same (for these Services). What to do?

Answer (score 7):

If you are using Spring Data REST **your idea is reasonable**. In your interface class just redefine the same method and add `@PreAuthorize` annotation to it. Code should be like this, though I didn't test it

```
@Repository
@RestResource(path = "changesets", rel = "changesets")
public interface ChangesetRepository extends JpaRepository<Changeset, Long> { 

@PreAuthorize("#pk == authentication.id") 
Page<Changeset> findAll(Pageable pageable);

}
```

Comment: For `PreAuthorize`, the `@Configuration` and `@EnableMethodSecurity` annotations are needed. However, I wonder if it is OK to place these on a `@Repository`.