# Access permissions for the Spring REST API

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-data-rest

Faced the problem of differentiating access rights of different user groups to the same objects in the database. I use Spring Data JPA, Spring REST and Spring Security. The front end will interact with the REST API and render everything on the client side. It is necessary to differentiate the rights to access REST API methods for different user groups. Until this moment, he posted @PreAuthorise annotations on repositories and their methods. The problems started already at the stage of writing tests, started looking for solutions on the Internet and came across an interesting answer to stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21577081/13226066. It says that repositories are not the best place to set rights, use services instead. Please tell me where you can read about such an architecture, preferably also with examples. And then, I feel, I shoot myself legs with my approach.

I think there should be some kind of layer between the repository interface and the controller, which Spring Data REST automatically generates

Comment: The advice that it is bad practice to use the `@PreAuthorize` annotation on the repository interface is right but there is no reason that it should not work. `@PreAuthorize` and `@PostAuthorize` work on any public method of a bean as long as the security configuration is setup.

Comment: I do not say that they do not work, they work. The question is how to do it right? How to follow the advice? How to build architecture correctly?  Maybe with the help of Spring REST this is impossible to achieve and I need to write controllers manually?

Comment: Theresa is no single right architecture. It all depends on the complexity of your problem an expected lifetime. For a very simple CRUD application with no business logic the Spring Data REST approach is fine. If you have business logic then adding controllers makes sense. The more complicated your business logic becomes it may be better to create separate units to encapsulate the logic.